# How to run UI tests with different configuration in Maven

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, ui-automation

I am new to automation UI testing and I am working on UI automation using Cucumber and Selenium.

So in my project, I created a Hook class to set up the web driver for testing. Something like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driver path");
driver = new chrome driver;
```

But if I want to run the same test with different browsers and different environments. For example, I want to run tests with chrome and environment  A and run the same test with firefox and environment B. I plan to create two properties files for different environments

```
env=qa
baseURl = http://qa......
username = test
password = test
```

and

```
env=dev
baseURl = http://dev......
username = test1
password = test1
```

And I want to just put a maven command like

```
mvn clean test broswer=chrome env=qa
```

to pick the properties from correct files and set the web driver according to the browser parameter.

Is it possible to do that? Any example for this kind of scenarios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using properties is a good idea. You are on the right track.

In order to load different properties, based on the environment, you can create multiple folders for properties files.

Let's assume that you store properties files under `src/main/java/dev/properties.properties`

Create multiple directories like:

```
src/main/java/qa
src/main/java/dev
src/main/java/prod
```

Create 1 properties file in each of the paths, just like I did at the beginning.

Now, you want to load correct properties with maven. You can use `maven profiles` to do that.

To your `pom.xml` add:

```
</dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <configuration.path>src/main/dev</configuration.path>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <configuration.path>src/main/prod</configuration.path>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Right under `</dependencies>`

As you can see, I've created 2 profiles. Their IDs are `dev` and `prod`. Both profiles have a `configuration.path` property pointing to your `.properties` file. 
To run the profile with maven commend you simply type `-PprofileId`. `-Pdev` for example

I hope you use `maven-surefire-plugin` because that's what I'll show in the example.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <configuration.path>${configuration.path}</configuration.path>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

The above is only PARTIAL configuration of `surefire-plugin`! Let's focus on `systemPropertyVariables`. In order to get properties from maven profile, you can load them into system, by passing `${configuration.paths}` variable into `surefire-plugin`. You can use the same name.

Now, you need to load properties from the `.properties` file into the system. I wrote a class to do that, to read `configuration.path`. You can use other solution.

```
public class Properties {
    private static java.util.Properties props;

    static {
        props = new java.util.Properties();

        String pathWithPropertiesFiles = System.getProperty("configuration.path");
        String[] paths = pathWithPropertiesFiles.split("[;]");

        Arrays.asList(paths).forEach(propertyPath -> Arrays.asList(Objects.requireNonNull(new File(propertyPath).listFiles())).forEach(propertyFile -> {
            InputStream input;
            try {
                input = new FileInputStream(propertyFile);
                props.load(input);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }));
    }

    public static String getValue(String key) {
        String envProperty = System.getenv(key);
        if (envProperty != null && !envProperty.equals("null")) {
            return envProperty;
        }

        String systemProperty = System.getProperty(key);
        if (systemProperty != null && !systemProperty.equals("null")) {
            return systemProperty;
        }

        return props.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

The above solution allows you to pass multiple paths into `configuration.path` the property, separated with `;`.

If you want to open the correct URL, you just use `Properties.getValue("baseURL");` It will get the URL from the correct path, based on the profile you selected.

Now, you can do similar stuff but for the browser. I strongly suggest reading about `BrowserFactory` or `Factory` design pattern. I can only provide you with hints on how to do that because my solution will probably won't work as you want.

Create additional profiles (you can use multiple profiles with maven) but for the browser.

```
<profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>chrome</id>
            <properties>
                <browser.type>chrome</browser.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
```

Invokation: `-Pchrome`

Remember to add it to `surefire-plugin`:

```
<configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <configuration.path>${configuration.path}</configuration.path>
                        <browser.type>${browser.type}</browser.type>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
```

All you have to do now, is think about, where do you instantiate your browser.

Simple solution would be (NON-THREAD SAFE!!!):

```
public class Browser {

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        String browserType = Properties.getValue("browser.type"); //it will get the `chrome` for profile `chrome`
        switch(browserType) {
            case "chrome": return new ChromeDriver();
        }
    }
}
```

All you have to do now is implement the solution in your framework. Add profiles, fill in the `switch` statement with all of the browsers used.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if the code looks rubbish, I tend to use Scala

---

This is a simple example in using properties which I've managed to get working:

Some code is omitted

```java
private String getBaseUrl() {
        String base = "";
        String foo = System.getProperty("browser", "chrome");
        switch (foo) {
            case "firefox":
                base = "https://www.google.co.uk";
                break;
            case "chrome":
                base = "https://www.bbc.co.uk";
                break;
        }
        return base;
    }



public void goTo() {
        this.driver.get(getBaseUrl());
    }
```

So when I use the command:

`mvn -Dbrowser=chrome test`

the driver will navigate to https://www.bbc.co.uk

and if I use:

`mvn -Dbrowser=firefox test`

then the driver will navigate to https://www.google.co.uk

If I just enter in:

`mvn test`

then it will navigate to bbc because of the default set to Chrome

---

If you have multiple things like different webdrivers etc then it can be done in the same way. Read in a property then based on the value of the property, initialise whichever driver you need.

Hope that helps